# Quarkus reactive with http request on ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: filter, quarkus, reactive, rest-client

I'm want to made a request on my ContainerRequestFilter

```
@Startup
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class SecurityOverrideFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    SsoClient ssoClient;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        String user = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");

        ssoClient.profile(user)
            .subscribe().with(
                    element -> {
                        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
                            @Override
                            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                                return new Principal() {
                                    @Override
                                    public String getName() {
                                        return element.getName();
                                    }
                                };
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean isUserInRole(String r) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean isSecure() {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                                return "basic";
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    failure -> logger.error(failure));
    }
}
```

This invocation works but it happens after the request, which means that when my service is invoked it still doesn't have the security context set.

I also try to do something like

```
@Blocking
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    String user = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization");

    Object profile = ssoClient.profile(user).await().atMost(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
    
    // if profile exists set the security context
}
```

But this throw into this:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The current thread cannot be blocked: vert.x-eventloop-thread-1
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:30)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:65)
            at pt.segsocial.ssn.async.infrastructure.http.security.SecurityOverrideFilter.filter(SecurityOverrideFilter.java:35)
            at pt.segsocial.ssn.async.infrastructure.http.security.SecurityOverrideFilter_ClientProxy.filter(Unknown Source)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ResourceRequestFilterHandler.handle(ResourceRequestFilterHandler.java:48)
            at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:131)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:48)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:23)
            at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:10)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:58)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:36)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.AbstractHttpAuthorizer.doPermissionCheck(AbstractHttpAuthorizer.java:110)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.AbstractHttpAuthorizer$2.accept(AbstractHttpAuthorizer.java:127)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.AbstractHttpAuthorizer$2.accept(AbstractHttpAuthorizer.java:116)
            at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.UniCallbackSubscriber.onItem(UniCallbackSubscriber.java:73)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:110)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:88)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.AbstractHttpAuthorizer.doPermissionCheck(AbstractHttpAuthorizer.java:116)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.AbstractHttpAuthorizer.checkPermission(AbstractHttpAuthorizer.java:93)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpAuthorizer.checkPermission(HttpAuthorizer.java:15)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:85)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$2.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:77)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:380)
            at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:373)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler$3$1.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:438)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler$3$1.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:428)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:60)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.DefaultUniEmitter.complete(DefaultUniEmitter.java:37)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnNull.lambda$failWith$1(UniOnNull.java:46)
            at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualBiConsumer.accept(SlowContextualBiConsumer.java:21)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniOnItem.lambda$transformToUni$4(UniOnItem.java:177)
            at io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateWithEmitter.subscribe(UniCreateWithEmitter.java:22)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler$3.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:428)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler$3.onItem(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:414)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.drain(UniMemoizeOp.java:160)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.onItem(UniMemoizeOp.java:180)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromItemSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromItemSupplier.java:29)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniMemoizeOp.subscribe(UniMemoizeOp.java:84)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
            at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:414)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.security.HttpSecurityRecorder$AbstractAuthenticationHandler.handle(HttpSecurityRecorder.java:368)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleHotReplacementRequest(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:135)
            at io.quarkus.ttp.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:437)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$5.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:433)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1284)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:141)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:68)
            at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:82)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:65)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:180)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:156)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:194)
            at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup$5.handle(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:185)
            at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureImpl$3.onSuccess(FutureImpl.java:141)
            at io.vertx.core.impl.future.FutureBase.lambda$emitSuccess$0(FutureBase.java:54)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
            at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
            at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
            at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
            at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any ideas how can I made a http request reactive on a filter?

Answer (score 1):

I end up with this solution

```
@Startup
public final class Filters {

    @Inject
    @RestClient
    SsoClient ssoClient;

    @ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
    public Uni<Void> preMatchingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        return Optional.ofNullable(requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization"))
                .<Uni<Void>>map(authorization -> {
                    return ssoClient.profile(authorization)
                                    .onItem()
                                    .invoke(profile -> {
                                        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                                                return () -> profile.getName();
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean isUserInRole(String r) {
                                                return profile.getRole().contains(r);
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public boolean isSecure() {
                                                return true;
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                                                return "basic";
                                            }
                                        });
                                    })
                                    .onItemOrFailure()
                                    .transform((item, failure) -> {
                                        logger.error(failure);
                                        return null;
                                    });
                        }
                )
                .orElse(Uni.createFrom().voidItem());
    }
}
```

What do you thing?

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?